# Exchange Management Console Missing Tabs

Tags: exchange-2010, emc

I am trying to set up exchange 2010, I want to configure the incoming mail but all the information I can find about says there should be tabs on the middle pane when I select hub transport..

I get none :-(

anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

(I am trying to set up the incoming addresses at the moment looking for "Accepted Domains" in case I should be doing something differently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually being a complete idiot here I am sorry to say that I was actually in the wrong branch of the tree.. really sorry guys and thank for your help..

the structure is largley mirrored so its easy to get confused (if your a noob.. and a bit of an idiot..)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your account is in the Organization Management group in AD...

Comment: In my case, for my client, this solved our problem and should be considered the answer!

Answer (score 0):

EMC (and EMS) shows you different tools based on your access level; if you don't have proper access rights, you are not only not able to perform a given task, but you don't even have UI access to it; you should check you have proper administrative rights on Exchange (not only on the domain, being Domain/Enterprise Administrator will be of no help if you are not in the proper Exchange administrative group).

If this is not the case, then you could have a corrupted installation of the Exchane Management Tools, or they could be at the wrong service pack level; try reinstalling them, or using them from another computer.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I am using the account that installed the server.. tried domain admin too.. boooo

Comment: I will try re-installing the management tools. I was hoping they had been replaced with something else or something but it sounds like its just broken..